# How to test if a method is called in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am currently struggling with testing one of my APIs `localhost:<port No.>/blah/`. My model is

```
class class1(models.Model):
    field_a = models.integerfield(...)
    field_b = models.integerfield(...)
```

I have also a serializer:

```
class Class1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Share
        fields = '__all__'
```

this is my view:

```
from .utils import prop
lass Class1View(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                mixins.CreateModelMixin, ):
    queryset = Share.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShareSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer, *args, **kwargs):
        _field_a = serializer.validated_data['field_a']
        _field_b = serializer.validated_data['field_b']

        if _field_a == 1:
            prop(test.objects.get(field_b = _field_b))
```

my urls.py is :

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blah', Class1View)
```

Also, I have utils.py

```
def prop(Share):
    pass
```

how can one write a test to check if the `prop` is called?

Answer (score 4):

You can use mocking to check if it was called. You can use the `@patch` decorator to mock the function the assert using `mockobject.called` here is sample code that should work for you

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, 
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestBlah(TestCase):
    @patch('view.prop') #this should be the path of the file where prop is to becalled
    def test_prop_is_called(self, mock_function):
            client = APICLient()
            client.post('/blah/' {'field_a':1, 'field_b': 1}, format='json')
            self.assert(mock_function.called)
```

I am writing this up in a bit of a hurry. Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

The way to test whether `prop()` is called is to construct a test input where `_field_a = 1`, and use assertions to check whether the results match your expectations.

If you want to test whether `prop()` does what it's supposed to do, you can simply write a unit test where you instantiate a `Share` object, pass it to `prop()`, and evaluate the output (or side-effects?) to see if it is what you expect.

If you just want to find out whether it's called, you could also just add a `print()` or logging statement inside the function.

On the other hand if you're asking how to tell whether the example *exactly as given* has been called (just a function containing `pass`) -- I don't know how to answer that.